# Linearlayout order is reversed on some devices

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, reverse

I have a `LinearLayout` and on some devices all the views are reversed.

The Good Version:

```
[b1] [b2] [b3]
```

On some devices:

```
[b3] [b2] [b1]
```

Why does that happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: no code to show for it?

Comment: I can virtually guarantee you this isn't what's happening. Almost all apps would be showing up this way.  Something else is going on.

Answer (score 7):

If you're targeting and testing on API level >=17 (i.e. Android 4.2) this might be caused by RTL support, as described [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html).

If you don't want this, you can either change [`android:layoutDirection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:layoutDirection) for each particular view (and since the default is `inherit`, the root view should suffice) or you can disable it for the whole application by setting [`android:supportsRtl="false"`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html) in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Or, you could also target an API level < 17, since it will then be disabled for compatibility (but this would lock you out of certain APIs).